# Display above div on hover

Tags: jquery, css

I have two divs, in a footer configuration. 
The aim is to, on hover, extend the footer upwards, by displaying an hidden div.

```css
#extendedFooter,
#test {
    display: none;
}
#standardFooter:hover~#extendedFooter,
#standardFooter:hover~#test{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id='extendedFooter'>
    It does not work :(
</div>

<div id='standardFooter'>
        Hover me
</div>

<div id='test'>
    Show me
</div>
```

I have managed to make the CSS work when the div to reveal is after the hovered div, but it does not work when the div to reveal is before the hovered div.

Is there any way to achieve this using only CSS? 
If not, is there a workaround using jQuery?

Comment: Can you alter your HTML?

Comment: Sure, with a constraint:
- #standardFooter is a footer (bottom: 0px), and its height is unknown at design time.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve that if you change your markup, because CSS is tree directional (Cascading) , so doesn't go up neither for siblings or parent(s).

And using `position:relative/absolute`

```css
section {
  position: relative
}

#extendedFooter,
#test {
  display: none;
}

#standardFooter:hover~#extendedFooter,
#standardFooter:hover~#test {
  display: block;
}

#extendedFooter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}
#standardFooter{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px
}
#test{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id='standardFooter'>
    Hover me
  </div>
  <div id='extendedFooter'>
    It does not work :(
  </div>
  <div id='test'>
    Show me
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use CSS sibling selectors with elements that come after - not before or up the DOM.

You could just add a parent, then trigger the hidden elements to show when you hover the parent.

```css
.item:not(:nth-child(2)) {
    display: none;
}
.col:hover .item {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div id='extendedFooter' class="item">
    It does not work :(
  </div>
  <div id='standardFooter' class="item">
    Hover me
  </div>
  <div id='test' class="item">
    Show me
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use a `flex` `column` with the `order` property to put the element you want to hover at the beginning of the list visually, but if you have an element before that is hidden, and you trigger it to be shown when you hover an element that comes after it, you're going to get a jumpy result... like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyKPoB

A way around that is to enable the hidden elements to be shown if you're hovering over any of them.

```css
.item:not(.hover) {
    display: none;
}
.item:hover ~ .item, .item:hover {
    display: block;
}
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div id='standardFooter' class="item hover">
    Hover me
  </div>
  <div id='extendedFooter' class="item">
    It does not work :(
  </div>
  <div id='test' class="item">
    Show me
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Keeping the normal flow is the best...+1